# Login into a Website

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I have read a number of posts related to this topic, tried a number of different methods and still can't get it to work.

The macro is working for the user name and password but login not working..

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer

Sub RepsolLogin()
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
Dim form As HTMLFormElement
MyURL = "https://login.repsol.com/es/Landing/AuthnPage?returnUrl=https://www.repsol.com/es_es/"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until MyBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document

Do While HTMLDoc.getElementById("gigya-login-form") Is Nothing
    DoEvents
Loop

Set form = HTMLDoc.getElementById("gigya-login-form")

form.all.UserName.Value = "xxx@xxx.com" 'Enter your email id here
form.all.Password.Value = "password" 'Enter your password here


form.submit
End Sub
```

Can anyone have a look an tell me how I must have the macro?

Comment: What happens when you try `HTMLDoc.querySelector("input[type='submit']").Click` instead of `form.submit`?

Comment: Please share more information about the "number of things" you have read and tried.  This is a pretty basic web scraping task and there are dozens of examples, I'm not sure what's not working for you.  (See "[mcve]")

Comment: It works perfectly, thank so much my friend. Sorry for the inconvenience but I'm a newbie.